# sql syntax wrong?

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables (users and friends):

```
users   : user_sid  | user_status
friends : user_sid  | user2_sid | type
```

i want to get list of online friends so i use this syntax :

```
SELECT user_sid 
FROM users 
WHERE users.user_status>0 
AND users.user_sid IN (
    (SELECT user_sid FROM friends WHERE user2_sid = '5604075088818445472' AND type=1) 
    UNION 
    (SELECT user2_sid FROM friends WHERE user_sid = '5604075088818445472' AND type=1)
) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

but i got this warning:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT user2_sid FROM friends WHERE user_sid = '56040750888184454...' at line 1

what i undertsand is

```
((SELECT user_sid FROM friends WHERE user2_sid = '5604075088818445472' AND type=1))
```

return empty and that give warning in mariadb.

anyone can help ?
thanks

i want to get list of online friends without warning if there is no friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax errors can't be due to what the subquery returns, because syntax is checked *before* executing anything.

The problem is that you have too many parentheses. It thinks you're doing `IN (list of values)` rather than `IN (subquery)`. Get rid of the extra parentheses around each query in the `UNION`.

```
SELECT user_sid 
FROM users 
WHERE users.user_status>0 
AND users.user_sid IN (
    SELECT user_sid FROM friends WHERE user2_sid = '5604075088818445472' AND type=1
    UNION 
    SELECT user2_sid FROM friends WHERE user_sid = '5604075088818445472' AND type=1
) 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```